# Android (Studio) - Multiple apps with the same id

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I started developping android apps with android studio (java) a few months ago.

My current app is called MyAverage and I have several versions of it, each one within a new project. Sadly I didn't know that they shouldn't have the same app id and now whenever I install/launch my newest version from within android studio on my mobile phone I get multiple MyAverages on my phone even if I uninstalled/deleted the other versions before.

[image: Multiple MyAverages]

Is there any way how I can fully remove the old MyAverages from my phone that I don't need and use anymore?

Comment: Post the code of your Manifest file. It seems you are adding intent-filter in different activities

Comment: Thank you that was indeed the solution. I just copy pasted the manifest code for my MainActivity to all other Activities in the Manifest. After deleting the intent-filters from all activities but the MainActivity, it works and I only see 1 MyAverage.

Answer (score 1):

In Your app level build.gradle
Change application Id

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapp.package"
        //Change your package name from here it will generate different package name apk for you
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 67
        versionName "0.6.7"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation":
                                      "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, now that's weird. I did change the applicationId to something completely different and still there are appearing 6 MyAverage icons after installing...